# Close running version of program before installing update (Inno Setup)

Tags: installation, inno-setup

This should be simple, I need to stop any previous version of my program from running when the installer starts.

Most people suggested making an `exe` which does this and calling it before Inno Setup starts.  I created an `exe` using AutoIt which kills all processes of my program.  The problem is I don't know how to get Inno Setup to call it before it installs anything.

How do I call an executable before installing files?

Alternatively, if I can just detect if a program is running and tell the user to close it, that would work too.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the application has a Mutex, you can add an `AppMutex` value in your Inno Setup installer and it will display a message telling the user to stop the program. You might be able to find the Mutex (if it's got one) by using SysInternals Process Explorer and selecting the program / process and looking at the Handles (CTRL-H) in the Lower Pane.

Here's a link to the a KB article that mentions several methods:
http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Detect_if_an_application_is_running

Alternatively, you might try this (UNTESTED) code in the `InitializeSetup`:

```pascal
[Setup]
;If the application has  Mutex, uncomment the line below, comment the InitializeSetup function out, and use the AppMutex.
;AppMutex=MyApplicationMutex

[Code]
const
  WM_CLOSE = 16;

function InitializeSetup : Boolean;
var winHwnd: Longint;
    retVal : Boolean;
    strProg: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    //Either use FindWindowByClassName. ClassName can be found with Spy++ included with Visual C++. 
    strProg := 'Notepad';
    winHwnd := FindWindowByClassName(strProg);
    //Or FindWindowByWindowName.  If using by Name, the name must be exact and is case sensitive.
    strProg := 'Untitled - Notepad';
    winHwnd := FindWindowByWindowName(strProg);
    Log('winHwnd: ' + IntToStr(winHwnd));
    if winHwnd <> 0 then
      Result := PostMessage(winHwnd,WM_CLOSE,0,0);
  except
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Mirtheil, this is exactly what I needed.  Everyone else provided reasonable answers but this turns out to be the perfect solution.

Comment: Actually, it didn't work on anything.  Once the correct window name was used, it does work on Windows 7 and other OSes.  I also added an alternative to FindWindowByWindowName which is FindWindowByClassName.  FindWindowByClassName might be a better choice if your program's window name changes.

Comment: For Inno 5.5.0+ there's a new solution, as I explain in my [late response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13583126/255257) to this question.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents), it is better to use the function `PrepareToInstall` instead of `InitializeSetup` to shutdown the application to update.

Comment: Sending `WM_CLOSE` does not necessary means application will exit. What if it has setting "Close to systray"? Could you suggest solution for this case? I guess one could send custom `WM_USER+X` message, or execute `taskkill`/`tskill` on worse case.

Comment: There is a simple solution for this problem, just put `CloseApplications=force` in *[Setup]* section of your InnoSetup project.

Answer (score 20):

In version [5.5.0](http://jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm#5.5.0) (Released on May 2012) Inno Setup added support for the [Restart Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373524.aspx) API on Windows Vista and newer.

Quote from MSDN linked documentation (emphasis mine):

> The primary reason software installation and updates require a system restart is that some of the files that are being updated are currently being used by a running application or service. **Restart Manager enables all but the critical applications and services to be shut down and restarted**. This frees the files that are in use and allows installation operations to complete. It can also eliminate or reduce the number of system restarts that are required to complete an installation or update.

The good thing is: you don't need to write custom code in the installer or your application to ask the user to close it, or close it automatically.

If you want your application to restart after the update is complete, you have to call the [`RegisterApplicationRestart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373347.aspx) function from your application first.

The default values for the new directives closes all the .exe, .dll and .chm files contained within the `[Files]` section of the installer.

The changes related to it are (from release notes):

> - Added new `[Setup]` section directive: `CloseApplications`, which defaults to `yes`. If set to yes and Setup is not running silently, Setup will now pause on the Preparing to Install wizard page if it detects applications using files that need to be updated by the `[Files]` or `[InstallDelete]` section, showing the applications and asking the user if Setup should automatically close the applications and restart them after the installation has completed. If set to yes and Setup is running silently, Setup will always close and restart such applications, unless told not to via the command line (see below).
> - Added new `[Setup]` section directive: `CloseApplicationsFilter`, which defaults to `*.exe,*.dll,*.chm`. Controls which files Setup will check for being in use. Setting this to `*.*` can provide better checking at the expense of speed.
> - Added new `[Setup]` section directive: `RestartApplications`, which defaults to `yes`. Note: for Setup to be able to restart an application after the installation has completed, the application needs to be using the Windows `RegisterApplicationRestart` API function.
> - Added new command line parameters supported by Setup: `/NOCLOSEAPPLICATIONS` and `/NORESTARTAPPLICATIONS`. These can be used to override the new `CloseApplications` and `RestartApplications` directives.
> - Added new `[Code]` support function: `RmSessionStarted`.
> - `TWizardForm`: Added new `PreparingMemo` property.

Comment: The `CloseApplicationsFilter` is key for many applications. Expand the filter to include the file types which are causing problems.

Comment: How to ask for the same while uninstall? Please help

Comment: Can someone help me with what flags to use with `RegisterApplicationRestart`? 

My app is already going to start by itself after system restart (e.g. it is an auto-start service) so my guess is that I should use `RestartNoReboot = 8`?

Also in the context of an Inno setup installing a new version (update), does using `RestartNoPatch = 4` mean that it won't automatically restart the app if it failed to update?

Comment: The meaning of the flags parameter is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerapplicationrestart

Answer (score 18):

I tried using the accepted answer (and the follow up by jachguate) but it wouldn't kill my application. It looks like part of the reason was that my application window had no text associated with it but whatever is the real reason, I used shell command to kill it and that worked. In the [code] section, you want to add the following function. It is called just before setup files are copied.

```
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
      ShellExec('open',  'taskkill.exe', '/f /im MyProg.exe','',SW_HIDE,ewNoWait,ErrorCode);
end;
```

Comment: Changing `ewNoWait` to `ewWaitUntilTerminated` may be required.

Comment: Currently instantly continues, and "applications are using files" shows up, but if `ewWaitUntilTerminated` is used, the problem is "Preparing to Install" hangs with empty body (until App's terminated).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using InnoSetup, you could look into getting your InnoSetup installer to do a Windows SendBroadcastMessage, and get your application to listen for that message.  When your application receives the message, it should shut itself down.

I've done this myself with an InnoSetup installer, and it works very well.

Comment: That won't work as the program has been released for years and I will need to close down old versions too.

Comment: @Conor can you tell me how you did it?

Comment: @Kainix: My app was written in Delphi.
Google "DefaultHandler windows messages broadcast" or similar and you should find your way.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a link to an Inno Setup script that prompts a user to close the target program, if it detects that the program is running.  After the user closes the program, they can click on a "Retry" button to proceed with the installation:

http://www.domador.net/extras/code-samples/inno-setup-close-a-program-before-reinstalling-it/

This script is based on a simpler script, found in the Inno Setup Extensions Knowledge Base:

http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Call_psvince.dll_on_install_and_uninstall

Answer (score 2):

I have had success using [WMIC](https://superuser.com/a/861229/59015) :

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
    ResultCode: Integer;
    wmicommand: string;
begin
    // before installing any file
    if CurStep = ssInstall then
    begin
        wmicommand := ExpandConstant('PROCESS WHERE "ExecutablePath like ''{app}\%%''" DELETE');

        // WMIC "like" expects escaped backslashes
        StringChangeEx(wmicommand, '\', '\\', True);

        // you can/should add an "if" around this and check the ResultCode
        Exec('WMIC', wmicommand, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    end;
end;
```

You can also do it in the `InitializeSetup` but if you do, keep in mind you don't have yet access to the `{app}` constant. My program doesn't ask for install path, but yours might.

Answer (score 2):

Add CloseApplications=true in [Setup] section.

If set to yes or force and Setup is not running silently, Setup will pause on the Preparing to Install wizard page if it detects applications using files that need to be updated by the [Files] or [InstallDelete] section, showing the applications and asking the user if Setup should automatically close the applications and restart them after the installation has completed.

Comment: `CloseApplications=true` is the default. This is already covered in the answer by @jachguate.

Answer (score 1):

InnoSetup allows you to attach Pascal scripts to various places in the build process.  Try attaching a script that calls ShellExecute.  (Which you may have to import to the script engine if it doesn't already have it.)

Comment: The script engine has Exec() so that's not the problem.  I can't figure out how to write the pascal code though to extract the bundled exe file and run it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to write your own DLL, you can use the tool help API for TlHelp32.pas to determine what applications are running, and then get a window handle for them using EnumWindows, then send a WM_CLOSE to the window handle.

It's a bit of a pain, but it should work:
I have some utility wrapper classes I developed with a friend a while back. Can't remember if we based it on someone else's code.

TWindows.ProcessISRunning and TWindows.StopProcess may help.

```
interface

uses
  Classes,
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  Contnrs,
  Messages;

type


TProcess = class(TObject)
  public
    ID: Cardinal;
    Name: string;
end;

TWindow = class(TObject)
  private
    FProcessID: Cardinal;
    FProcessName: string;
    FHandle: THandle;
    FProcessHandle : THandle;
    function GetProcessHandle: THandle;
    function GetProcessID: Cardinal;
    function GetProcessName: string;
  public
    property Handle : THandle read FHandle;
    property ProcessName : string read GetProcessName;
    property ProcessID : Cardinal read GetProcessID;
    property ProcessHandle : THandle read GetProcessHandle;
end;

TWindowList = class(TObjectList)
  private
    function GetWindow(AIndex: Integer): TWindow;
  protected

  public
    function Add(AWindow: TWindow): Integer; reintroduce;
    property Window[AIndex: Integer]: TWindow read GetWindow; default;
end;

TProcessList = class(TObjectList)
  protected
    function GetProcess(AIndex: Integer): TProcess;
  public
    function Add(AProcess: TProcess): Integer; reintroduce;
    property Process[AIndex: Integer]: TProcess read GetProcess; default;
end;

TWindows = class(TObject)
  protected
  public
    class function GetHWNDFromProcessID(ProcessID: Cardinal; BuildList: Boolean = True): THandle;
    class function GetProcessList: TProcessList;
    class procedure KillProcess(ProcessName: string);
    class procedure StopProcess(ProcessName: string);
    class function ExeIsRunning(ExeName: string): Boolean;
    class function ProcessIsRunning(PID: Cardinal): Boolean;
end;

implementation

uses
  Forms,
  Math,
  PSAPI,
  TlHelp32;

const
  cRSPUNREGISTERSERVICE = 0;
  cRSPSIMPLESERVICE = 1;

type

TProcessToHWND = class(TObject)
  public
    ProcessID: Cardinal;
    HWND: Cardinal;
end;

function RegisterServiceProcess(dwProcessID, dwType: DWord): DWord; stdcall; external 'KERNEL32.DLL';
function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(lpDirectoryName: PChar;
  var lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller, lpTotalNumberOfBytes: TLargeInteger;
  lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes: PLargeInteger): Boolean; stdcall;external 'KERNEL32.DLL' name 'GetDiskFreeSpaceExA'

var
  GProcessToHWNDList: TObjectList = nil;

function EnumerateWindowsProc(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  proc: TProcessToHWND;
begin
  if Assigned(GProcessToHWNDList) then
  begin
    proc := TProcessToHWND.Create;
    proc.HWND := hwnd;
    GetWindowThreadProcessID(hwnd, proc.ProcessID);
    GProcessToHWNDList.Add(proc);
    Result := True;
  end
  else
    Result := False; // stop enumeration
end;

{ TWindows }

class function TWindows.ExeIsRunning(ExeName: string): Boolean;
var
  processList: TProcessList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;

  processList := GetProcessList;
  try
    for i := 0 to processList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if (UpperCase(ExeName) = UpperCase(processList[i].Name)) or
          (UpperCase(ExeName) = UpperCase(ExtractFileName(processList[i].Name))) then
      begin
        Result := True;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    processList.Free;
  end;
end;

class function TWindows.GetHWNDFromProcessID(
  ProcessID: Cardinal; BuildList: Boolean): THandle;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;

  if BuildList or (not Assigned(GProcessToHWNDList)) then
  begin
    GProcessToHWNDList.Free;
    GProcessToHWNDList := TObjectList.Create;
    EnumWindows(@EnumerateWindowsProc, 0);
  end;

  for i := 0 to GProcessToHWNDList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if TProcessToHWND(GProcessToHWNDList[i]).ProcessID = ProcessID then
    begin
      Result := TProcessToHWND(GProcessToHWNDList[i]).HWND;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;


class function TWindows.GetProcessList: TProcessList;
var
  handle: THandle;
  pe: TProcessEntry32;
  process: TProcess;
begin
  Result := TProcessList.Create;

  handle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  pe.dwSize := Sizeof(pe);
  if Process32First(handle, pe) then
  begin
    while True do
    begin
      process := TProcess.Create;
      process.Name := pe.szExeFile;
      process.ID := pe.th32ProcessID;
      Result.Add(process);
      if not Process32Next(handle, pe) then
        Break;
    end;
  end;
  CloseHandle(handle);
end;

function EnumWindowsProc(Ahwnd : HWND;      // handle to parent window
  ALParam : Integer) : BOOL;stdcall;
var
  List : TWindowList;
  Wnd : TWindow;
begin
  Result := True;
  List := TWindowList(ALParam);
  Wnd := TWindow.Create;
  List.Add(Wnd);
  Wnd.FHandle := Ahwnd;
end;


class procedure TWindows.KillProcess(ProcessName: string);
var
  handle: THandle;
  pe: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  // Warning: will kill all process with ProcessName
  // NB won't work on NT 4 as Tool Help API is not supported on NT

  handle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  try
    pe.dwSize := Sizeof(pe);

    if Process32First(handle, pe) then
    begin
      while True do begin
        if (UpperCase(ExtractFileName(pe.szExeFile)) = UpperCase(ExtractFileName(ProcessName))) or
           (UpperCase(pe.szExeFile) = UpperCase(ProcessName)) then
        begin
          if not TerminateProcess(OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, False,
                                    pe.th32ProcessID), 0) then
          begin
            raise Exception.Create('Unable to stop process ' + ProcessName + ': Error Code ' + IntToStr(GetLastError));
          end;
        end;
        if not Process32Next(handle, pe) then
          Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(handle);
  end;
end;

class function TWindows.ProcessIsRunning(PID: Cardinal): Boolean;
var
  processList: TProcessList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;

  processList := GetProcessList;
  try
    for i := 0 to processList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if processList[i].ID = PID then
      begin
        Result := True;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    processList.Free;
  end;
end;

class procedure TWindows.StopProcess(ProcessName: string);
var
  processList: TProcessList;
  i: Integer;
  hwnd: THandle;
begin
  // Warning: will attempt to stop all process with ProcessName
  if not Assigned(GProcessToHWNDList) then
    GProcessToHWNDList := TObjectList.Create
  else
    GProcessToHWNDList.Clear;

  // get list of all current processes
  processList := GetProcessList;
  // enumerate windows only once to determine the window handle for the processes
  if EnumWindows(@EnumerateWindowsProc, 0) then
  begin
    for i := 0 to processList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if UpperCase(ExtractFileName(processList[i].Name)) = UpperCase(ExtractFileName(ProcessName)) then
      begin
        hwnd := GetHWNDFromProcessID(processList[i].ID, False);
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;


{ TProcessList }

function TProcessList.Add(AProcess: TProcess): Integer;
begin
  Result := inherited Add(AProcess);
end;

function TProcessList.GetProcess(AIndex: Integer): TProcess;
begin
  Result := TProcess(Items[AIndex]);
end;

{ TWindowList }

function TWindowList.Add(AWindow: TWindow): Integer;
begin
  Result := inherited Add(AWindow);
end;

function TWindowList.GetWindow(AIndex: Integer): TWindow;
begin
  Result := TWindow(Items[AIndex]);
end;

{ TWindow }

function TWindow.GetProcessHandle: THandle;
begin
  if FProcessHandle = 0 then
    FProcessHandle := OpenProcess(Windows.SYNCHRONIZE or Windows.PROCESS_TERMINATE,
     True, FProcessID);
  Result := FProcessHandle;
end;

function TWindow.GetProcessID: Cardinal;
var
  Pid : Cardinal;
begin
  if FProcessID = 0 then
  begin
    Pid := 1;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(Handle, Pid);
    FProcessID := Pid;
  end;
  Result := FProcessID;
end;


function TWindow.GetProcessName: string;
var
  Buffer : packed array [1..1024] of char;
  len : LongWord;
begin
  FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
  if FProcessName = '' then
  begin
    len := GetWindowModuleFileName(Handle, @Buffer[1], 1023);
    FProcessName := Copy(Buffer, 1, Len);
  end;
  Result := FProcessName;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Failed to compile in InnoSetup, could anyone fix it? I never used pascal before.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the easier way to perform this may be creating a DLL in Delphi that detects if your program is running and ask the user to close it, put that DLL in your setup and use the flag "dontcopy" (check in http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/ under Pascal Scripting \ Using DLLs for an example).

Btw, next time use mutexes, Inno Setup also support that and is far more easier.

EDIT: and for extracting a file (if you want to use that .exe you mention), just use ExtractTemporaryFile().